# I lost all the iOS simulators in Appcelerator Studio? How do I get them back?

Tags: ios, appcelerator-studio

I haven't been able to build to my iPhone 6 so yesterday I was advised to add to Xcode (in Preferences > Accounts tab) the Apple ID of the leader of our informal team.

Still wasn't able to build to my iPhone, and today I realized that all my iOS simulators have disappeared from Appcelerator Studio.

What did I do to disappear them from this project? And how do I restore them? (I see that they're still there in another project.)

Comment: How did you eventually fix it? I just got the same issue. Everything was working fine, and then iOS simulators mysteriously disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](http://childofcode.com/appcelerator-studio-ios-simulation-gone/).

1.Go to Home(jacklee).

2.Go to Folder and find the titanium folder (.titanium).

3.find the files calling "config.json" and Edit the files.

4.change the ""selected": "3.5.1.GA"" to the Latest SDK (any GA Version should be fine).

5.Delete the RC(beta)SDK.

Comment: Also try this, just worked for me in 2020: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/

Answer (score -1):

Problem might be with your deployment target selection in the tiapp.xml file, make sure you select '**iPhone**' checkbox in the tiapp.xml editor of your project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did check that before posting my question.

Comment: I just got the same problem. All my Simulators just disappeared.